# How to calculate leaves based on color using Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, calculation

I have an attendance excel sheet that includes staff names and time in and out.

[image]

consider L grey color = 1 and Pink color cell consider as 0.50.

here I want to calculate for the column

"emp4" have 2.50 (leaves taken), [Having two L mentioned in grey cell and one pink cell includes 1:30PM]

emp6 have 0.50(leave taken), [Having 2:30PM in pink color]

emp8 have 1(leave taken). [Having 12.36PM and 3:30PM - two pink color cells. so 0.50 + 0.50 =1 ]

So I need to calculate leaves by month-wise based on the cell color. Can anyone please help me to do this?

Comment: Hi Mic wer :) Could you edit your question to include any attempts you have already made?

Comment: @tjheslin1 no idea how to do this? :(

Answer (score 0):

The colour of a cell does not contain any information about the cell value, so it can't be used as an input for whatever formula.

However, you can turn things around: you can create conditional formatting, colouring the cell based on its value. As such, the colour of the value will be a measure for the cell's value and you can make it look like colour being based on colours (although in background they are always based on values).

Comment: Thanks but I didn't understand how to use this in conditional formatting. please give an example. Thanks you

Comment: How to calculate one grey cell =0.50 so if two cells having grey color means it should calculate 0.50 +0.50 =1 . so it means 1 leave taken

Comment: same like one cell having pink color it means 0.50 (half day leave )

Comment: any updates plz